# Cannot update entity on mongodb spring boot unit test having unique constraint

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin, junit, repository

I have the following model (kotlin):

```
@ApiModel(description = "Showtime model specifying the scheduled movie display")
@Document
class Showtime(
    @ApiModelProperty(notes="Date of movie display")
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    val date: LocalDateTime,
    var movie: Movie,
    var price: BigDecimal
) {

    
}
```

So I'm trying to test that mongodb updates a record on save when it's present instead of attempting to insert it with this:

```
@Testcontainers
@DataMongoTest
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = [MongoInitializer::class])
internal class ShowtimeDaoTest {
    @Test
    fun `when inserting a modified showtime movie at the same date the database allows it`() {
        // Cleanup
        showtimeDao.deleteAll()

        val movie = Movie(1, "The Fast and the Furious", "tt0232500")
        val showtimeDate = LocalDateTime.of(2021, Month.DECEMBER, 1, 3, 0, 0)
        val movie2 = Movie(2, "The Fast and the Furious 2", "tt0232600")

        // Save first movie
        val showtime = Showtime(showtimeDate, movie, BigDecimal(43.5))
        val showtimeByDate = showtimeDao.save(showtime)

// this doesn't work either
//        val showtimeByDate = showtimeDao.findOneByDate(showtimeDate)!!

        // Update the saved record and it should update instead of inserting
        showtimeByDate.movie = movie2

        showtimeDao.save(showtimeByDate)

        val showtimeByDate2 = showtimeDao.findOneByDate(showtimeDate)!!
        assertEquals(movie2.name, showtimeByDate2.movie.name)
    }
}
```

My service does the same and when the project is running it works correctly, but in the  test the second save always fails with:

E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.showtime index: date dup key: { date: new Date(1638338400000) }; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.showtime index: date dup key: { date: new Date(1638338400000) }
org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.showtime index: date dup key: { date: new Date(1638338400000) }; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.showtime index: date dup key: { date: new Date(1638338400000) }

ShowtimeDao:

```
@Component
interface ShowtimeDao : MongoRepository<Showtime?, String?> {
    // By the database constraint we are guaranteed to only have one item for a given date, so no need to do findAll
    fun findOneByDate(name: LocalDateTime?): Showtime?
}
```

ShowtimeService:

```
@Service
class ShowtimeService(private val showtimeDao: ShowtimeDao) {

    
    fun insertOrUpdateShowtime(showtime: Showtime): Showtime {
        val showtimeToUpdate = showtimeDao.findOneByDate(showtime.date)
        return if (showtimeToUpdate == null) {
            showtimeDao.save(showtime)
        } else {
            if (showtimeToUpdate.movie.id == showtime.movie.id &&
                showtimeToUpdate.price == showtime.price) {
                // Same movie, price and datetime, nothing to be done
                showtimeToUpdate
            } else {
                showtimeToUpdate.movie = showtime.movie
                showtimeToUpdate.price = showtime.price
                showtimeDao.save(showtimeToUpdate)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

build.gradle.kts:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile
import org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.bundling.BootBuildImage

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.5.3"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.21"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.5.21"
    id("org.springframework.experimental.aot") version "0.10.2-SNAPSHOT"
    id("org.graalvm.buildtools.native") version "0.9.1"
}

group = "com.cinema"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_16

repositories {
    maven { url = uri("https://repo.spring.io/snapshot") }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.8.0")
    implementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.8.0")
    implementation ("jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.2")
    implementation ("org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.2")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.2")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
        exclude(module = "mockito-core")
    }
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
    testImplementation("com.ninja-squad:springmockk:2.0.1")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:mongodb:1.15.3")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter:1.15.3")

}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "16"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<BootBuildImage> {
    builder = "paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny"
    environment = mapOf("BP_NATIVE_IMAGE" to "true")
}
```

The problem is that in the test when I retrieve the model, it doesn't contain the __id field indicating it's saved, I tried using the @Commit attribute in the test and many other things trying for the save to persist or flush in case that's the problem but nothing worked.

In case you need it I can provide the whole project, it's a small sample project but I'm not sure it's allowed to link to files here.

Answer (score -1):

The solution was adding an Id field to the model:

```
@Document
class Showtime(
    @ApiModelProperty(notes="Date of movie display")
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    val date: LocalDateTime,
    var movie: Movie,
    var price: BigDecimal
) {
    @Id
    var id: String? = null;
}
```

This might be a bug since it only fails on tests, but for now it fixes it.

Comment: However ```Showtime``` has primary key, date field is still unique.

Comment: Then why does it fail when the record doesn't have an Id field?